# Poacher's Mark and Flicker Strike Application

Tags: path-of-exile

Currently trying to build a capable Assassin for Kalandra league. I'm confused as to how Marks work, as I see there have been some changes. If I have flicker strike linked to multi-strike and poacher's mark, am I applying the mark to everything I hit, so I'll always be hitting something that's marked? Or does it only mark the first thing I hit when I start the chain? I see the marks on the enemies for despair curse that I've got on Blasphemy Support, but not the Poacher's Mark symbol, and am wondering if I"m actually getting benefits of Mark Mastery in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curse is a blanket term for hexes and marks, i.e. if an effect applies to curses, it applies to both. Despair and Blasphemy Support are hexes while Poachers Mark is a, well, mark. In other words, blasphemy does not interact with marks, as you'll see that they don't share any tags. On this note, Multistrike does not interact with marks either as it's just an attack modifier.

What you want is [Mark on Hit](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Mark_On_Hit_Support) connected to a mark in a 2-link which will make any attack apply the mark.

Comment: Mark On Hit doesn't need to be in the same link as Flicker Strike. As long as it's linked to a mark, any attack hit will proc the mark.